# How do I read a in incoming POST Multipart request using ruby and tcpserver

Tags: ruby, curl

I have created a very simple server:

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open 2000
puts "Listening on port 2000"

loop {
  client = server.accept

  client.puts "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
  response = "My super slim ruby http server"
  client.puts response

  received = client.recv(1024)
  puts received
  puts "\n"

  client.close
}
```

So far, it serves my purpose, which is to print out the requests that might come from a given client. However, if I use, for example, the following curl command to create a request:

`curl -F "data=someData" http://localhost:2000`

My ruby server only prints out the HTTP headers, but not the body of the request.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have to call recv again to get the body:

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open 2000
puts "Listening on port 2000"

loop {
  client = server.accept

  client.puts "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
  response = "My super slim ruby http server"
  client.puts response

  headers = client.recv(1024)
  headers =~ /Content-Length: (\d+)/ # get content length
  body    = $1 ? client.recv($1.to_i) : '' # <- call again to get body if there is one

  puts headers + body

  client.close
}
```

Comment: I think it's more correct to look at the headers to see how long the body is and then read in that amount. Updated my answer with that change.

Comment: That has already helped me a lot. However, I noticed that I can't read more bytes than what I have read in the first client.recv(). So the call for the body will only read up to 1024 bytes in this example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bundacia, I ended up mixing what you sent and some other findings and this is the result:

```
#!/bin/ruby

require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open 2000
puts "Listening on port 2000"

loop {
client = server.accept

client.puts "HTTP/1.1 200/OK\r\nContent-type:text/xml\r\n\r\n"
response = "My super slim ruby http server"
client.puts response

all_data = []
i = 1024
firstrun = "yes"
while i > 0
    partial_data = client.recv(i)
    if (firstrun == "no")
        i = 0
    end
    if (firstrun == "yes")
        partial_data =~ /Content-Length: (\d+)/ # get content length
        length = $1
        if (nil != length && !length.empty?)
            i = length.to_i
            firstrun = "no"
        end
    end

    all_data << partial_data
end

puts all_data.join()

client.close
}
```